# PHP and mySQL getting a image root folder

Tags: php

I am using DELIMETER in PHP to call in a row from a table but i need to call in a image from a row in the table and the image folder. How do i do this?

Current code is below. How do i add in the folder location that is holding my images (folder name is image and is in the same folder as this code)

```
while ($row = fetch_array($query)) {
        $product = <<<DELIMETER

        <div class="product-card">
          <div class="product-image">
        <a href="item.php?id={$row['product_id']}">

        <img src={$row['image']} alt="image" style="width:50px;"></a>
```

Comment: You mean add it in like `src="image/{$row['image']}"` ???

Comment: i have tried 100 different ways this is the first thats worked thank you, youve saved my college project